# Codeigniter Link to Stylesheet

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am trying to learn Codeigniter. I have built a simple MVC following the tutorials on the CI site. This is my controller...

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home'){

        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is the header template...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?> - WurkWithUs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ci/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ci/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/css/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wurk With Us</h1>
```

The style sheets work when I use an absolute path like the one above. However if I try to use something like...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url()?>css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

I get a blank page. When I "view page source" my style line looks like...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="
```

I have tried to follow the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745153/codeigniter-php-stylesheet-link-how) and I get the same results i.e. document stops being parsed at the "href=" line.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to load my stylesheets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had this issue many, many times. I'd bet money you're not loading in the [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html). It does not autoload, so either load it in your controller or autoload it.

If you choose to lead it in your controller, call

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

before you load the view.

The reason you see the `href` blank in the source is because there was a PHP error at that point (it could not find the method `base_url()`)

Comment: Yup just figured that out thank for your help. I was just writing my own answer. Aloha

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php base_url("css/bootstrap.css"); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: That's a no go. Those double qoutes wouldn't work inside the href anyways. I tried every variation of this suggestion with different ways of escaping the quotes and got the same result.

Comment: @shakabra - This is not the solution to your problem, however it is the correct way to use the `base_url` function.  The quotes are there because you are passing a string to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

and this in the head tag

```
<?=link_tag('css/style.css')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load the "url" helper. 
Load your helper in autoload.php

```
Like that way :: $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

This will auto load your helper every time. So, you need not to load it again and again in every controller.

or

If You want to load this helper for specific controller, then load the helper in your controller call

```
Like that way :: $this->load->helper('url');
```